# overflow-y: scroll causing issues with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add overflow-y:scroll to the .nav styling the button to open the navigation requires 2 clicks. Change this to overflow: none and it only requires 1 click as intended when using the following jquery:

```
$(function(){
  var nav = $('.nav'),
  navBut = $('.navBut');

  navBut.click(function(){
  if(nav.width() === 0){
    nav.stop().animate({ width: '15%', opacity: '1.0' }, 300);
  } else {
    nav.stop().animate({ width: '0', opacity: '0.0' }, 300);
  }
});
```

Can anybody see why this would be the case or how I can solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ubxyw0t/2/

Comment: what browser are you using?  i just tried this in Chrome and it works fine with overflow set to "none" or "scroll"

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox and it works fine. In the latest version of Chrome it requires 2 clicks to open

Comment: I'm on the latest version of Chrome for the mac

Comment: I'm using Windows. Is it possibly a bug? And would there be a workaround in the jquery?

Comment: The answer below solved it! Thanks for your help Da Rod.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking if the `width` of `.nav` is equal to `0`, you need to check to see if it is less than or equal to `0`.

Your original issue only seemed to effect certain browsers. It seems like some browsers would give the element a negative width when the `overflow` property was set to `scroll`. I guess this is just a cross-browser rendering inconsistency.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4c4r6wm/)

```
var nav = $('.nav'),
    navBut = $('.navBut');

navBut.on('click', function () {
    if (nav.width() <= 0) {
        nav.stop().animate({
            width: '15%',
            opacity: '1.0'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        nav.stop().animate({
            width: '0',
            opacity: '0.0'
        }, 300);
    }
});
```